# Stop being so pedantic. Your (what noun?) has no place here

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a term that means essentially “pedantic-ness”. What is the correct term?

Comment: Any clues as to your thought-process, Mr Downvote?

Comment: Sorry, "Misters"....

Comment: Probably because the answer can be found in a dictionary.

Comment: @Hugo (and downvoters): yes, once you know the word, you can easily look it up in the dictionary. But if you simply can't think of the word, or don't even know it exists, then where exactly are you going to look?

Comment: @Martha I mean you can look up the word you do know (*pedantic*) in a dictionary and find *pedantry*.

Comment: @Martha same excuse have been used in jokes, but you have good point. :)

Comment: @Hugo: Sure he could look up pedantic and find pedantry -- if he already knew that there was such a word.

Comment: @Jay: The word *pedantic* is in the question.  He therefore did already know of the word.  You can google "pedantic noun", etc, and  you have the answer right away.

Comment: @Hugo & drɱ65 Not true. I could see no mention of "pedantry" when I looked up "pedantic" in the dictionary. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/pedantic

Comment: Also (now that I know them) I have been able to look up both "pedantry" and "pedanticism" in the dictionary, and either seem suitable. It is helpful to be told that the more common-place one is "pedantry".

Comment: @Hugo: Well, we could argue in circles about this for days. But you're saying that assuming that the OP knew that there was a noun form of the adjective "pedantic", and assuming that he knew that a Google search of "pedantic noun" would find this word, then he could have easily answered his own question. Well, sure. But he obviously knew neither of those things and was asking for help. Why not just answer the poor guy's question rather than ridiculing him for asking? Sometimes it's easier to help people than to step on them.

Comment: @Jay Well, questions here are meant to show some research effort, check the up/downvote tooltips and the [FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq#questions). And this is a question about pedantry :) Anyway, I did upvote the best answer.

Comment: @Hugo Stop being so pedantic. Your pedantry has no place here. :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

My choice would be [pedantry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pedantry).

Comment: Are there really places where pedantry is unwelcome? :)

Comment: That's probably better than my choice, which is a 3-letter word that rhymes with grass.

Comment: You could also consider `pedanticism` - that's the one that comes to mind for me, but I'm not saying it's any better!

Answer (score 1):

In simple English, you may say: 
"Stop being so pedantic. Your style is out-of-place here."
or
"Stop being so pedantic. Get off your high horse."

"Get off your High Horse" means to say, "get off your lofty perch," from which perch, you are "looking down" upon us, disdainfully.